# Execlude certain values in the group stage in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, filter, aggregation-framework

In my code i am trying to collect the available filters however there are fields that were not
filled by the user and left as empty strings e.g the "brands" field. however, empty strings should not be considered as a valid value

this is my group stage:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        sizes: { $addToSet: '$combinations.size' },
        colors: { $push: '$combinations.color' },
        brands: { $addToSet: '$brand' },
        topPrice: { $max: `$price.${req.query.reg || 'aud'}` },
        bottomPrice: { $min: `$price.${req.query.reg || 'aud'}` },
    },
},
```

the brands field will be:
`[ "" ]`

what i wanted is
`[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregating.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "brands": {
        "$addToSet": {
          $cond: [
            {$eq: ["$brand",""]},  //if brands is empty string,
            "$$REMOVE",            //then, REMOVE it
            "$brand"               //else, keep it
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H3C21XMe_rL)